# MySQL Config Settings for an EC2 Micro Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, configuration

Anyone have some good MySQL config settings for an EC2 Micro instance? The sample config files that come along with MySQL are like 10 years old--one assumes you have a max 64MB of system RAM. Does anyone have some well-tuned settings for a micro EC2 instance? Or even a small instance?

Here are some settings that are used for RDS MySQL instances (RDS being sort of a stand-alone EC2 instance that's optimized to run MySQL):

```
binlog_cache_size=32768
innodb_buffer_pool_size={DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=8388608
innodb_log_file_size=134217728
key_buffer_size=16777216
max_binlog_size=134217728
max_connections={DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}
read_buffer_size=262144
max_md_buffer_size=524288
thread_stack=196608
```

`DBInstanceClassMemory` appears to be a pseudo-variable that RDS makes available to you in your config. In the case of a small instance, then, this value should be 1.7GB or 1825361100.

Do these sound like reasonable settings to use, scaling that `DBInstanceClassMemory` down to 613MB for a micro instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the tuning-primer.sh on your micro instance for automatic suggestions based on your current database usage.

http://www.day32.com/MySQL/